# Jquery Slideshow with numbers--help have number links stay color until another is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, slideshow

I have researched this to no end and have tried other answers to similar questions but have had no luck. I would like the numbers (that are links) to change to a color when selected and remain that color UNTIL another number/link is selected and it change back to its original color.

I have gotten it the script to work so that it changes color when selected...but it wont change back when the next link is selected. Below is my code (i apologize if its not showing correctly). If you need to see more please let me know! Here is the link to the live test page: http://bmww.com/clients/index3/casestudies/cabrini_casestudy3.html

Script:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function () {
$('.slideshow').blinds();

})
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
    });
});
    </script>
```

And this is my css:

```
<style>

a{
color: #666335;
}

a.clicked{
color: #D85D27;
}
```

and this is my html:

```
<a href="#" class="change_link" onclick="$('.slideshow').blinds_change(1); return     false">1</a>
<a href="#" class="change_link" onclick="$('.slideshow').blinds_change(2); return false">2</a>
<a href="#" class="change_link"  onclick="$('.slideshow').blinds_change(3); return false">3</a>
<a href="#" class="change_link"  onclick="$('.slideshow').blinds_change(4); return false">4</a>
<a href="#" class="change_link" onclick="$('.slideshow').blinds_change(5); return false">5</a>
<a href="#" class="change_link" onclick="$('.slideshow').blinds_change(6); return false">6</a>
<a href="cabrini_casestudy2.html" class="ex1" >     >> </a>
```

Answer (score 2):

your code will work if same link is clicked again.

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a.change_link').click(function(){
    $('.clicked').removeClass('clicked');
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
    });

});
```